# Syntax error at "def" in Django views using sessions

Tags: python, django, session, view, syntax-error

This is in an app in a Django project, in the views file for that app. The app is installed in settings.py, but it throws the error before it should be calling the view up.

I am getting an error at the "f" in "def" at CouponForm, it says that it is a SyntaxError but I can't fing the problem. The urlconf only references the manageCoupons function.
Thanks in advance for any help!

views.py:

```
from models import Coupon
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.http import HttpResponse

def CouponList(req):
    c = Coupon.objects.all()
    return render(req,'coupon_list.html',{'title':'Coupons','coupons':c}

def CouponForm(req1):
    if 'name' in req1.GET and 'desc' in req1.GET:
        name1 = req1.GET['cname']
        desc = req1.GET['desc']
        c = Coupon(name=name1, description=desc)
        c.save()
        success = True
    else:
        success = False
    return render(req1,'coupon.html',{'title':'New Coupon','success':success,})

def CouponDelete(req2):
    if 'name' in req2.GET:
        name1 = req2.GET['name']
        c = Coupon.objects.filter(name=name1)
        c.delete()
        success = True
    else:
        success = False
    return render(req2,'coupon_delete.html',{'title':'Delete Coupon','success':success}


def manageCoupons(request):
    if 'passwrd' in request.GET:
        psswrd = request.GET['passwrd']
        if psswrd == 'password0':
            return CouponList(request)
        elif psswrd == 'password1':
            request.session["function"] = 'cform'
            return CouponForm(request)
        elif psswrd == 'password2':
            request.session["function"] = 'cdelete'
            return CouponDelete(request)
    elif "function" in request.session:
        if request.session["function"] == 'cdelete':
            return CouponDelete(request)
        elif request.session["function"] == 'cform':
            return CouponForm(request)
    else:
        return HttpResponse("<a href='/'>Home</a>")
```

Comment: Please, `Use the function naming rules: lowercase with words separated by underscores as necessary to improve readability.`

Comment: sorry, I'm still kinda new to python and Django.

Answer (score 3):

```
def CouponList(req):
    c = Coupon.objects.all()
    return render(req,'coupon_list.html',{'title':'Coupons','coupons':c})
                                                                        ^
                                                                        |
                                                              You are missing this bracket
```

Comment: Thanks! I actually just found it after a lot of searching. I knew it had to be something simple that I was missing

Answer (score 1):

You are missing `)` at this line:

```
render(req2,'coupon_delete.html',{'title':'Delete Coupon','success':success}
```

should be:

```
render(req2,'coupon_delete.html',{'title':'Delete Coupon','success':success})
```